# Passing an id to a hyperlink's href within a view

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application I'm aiming to display plan id when I hover over a link. Basically get the id of the plan's table from the database. I'm getting an error of:

```
Undefined variable: plan
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Plan;


class PlanController extends Controller
{

    public function getPlan(Request $request, $id){

          $plan = Plan::find($id);


        return redirect()->route('index');

    }

}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/plan_id/{id}', [

    'uses' => 'PlanController@getPlan',
    'as' => 'get-plan'

]);
```

View with the link:

```
  <a href="{{route('get-plan', ['id' => $plan->id])}}" type="submit" id="basic" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign up with Basic </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the view where you're building the link, instead of using redirecting:

```
return view('view', compact('plan'));
```

And as I told you in your other question, if you're using redirect, you should use `->with('plan', $plan);` to flash data into the session.

Comment: Im using the return view. I'm still getting undefined in the view.

Comment: will i need to change anything in the hyperlink href ?

Comment: @steven if you're using `return view('view', compact('plan'));` and it still gives you the same error, it means some another method is returning the view.

Comment: Is my href code correct? if I include your code of: return view('view', compact('plan'));

Comment: Why am i still getting undefined variable: plan :(

Answer (score 0):

In that code, the variable $plan is local to the function. It does not have external scope.
You can either declare it as global

```
global $plan;
```

or use public variable on the class:

```
$this->plan
```